# Firebase Firestore: How to get ref from snapshot via using async/await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using **Cloud Firestore** in **Firebase functions** with **Node.js 8**

Simple open question is: Does it possible to get **ref** from `.get()` via using **async/await**?

**Example:**

```
const snapshot = await db.collection(/*..*/).doc(/*..*/).get();
const data = snapshot.data();
const ref = /* ???? */
// Then using...
ref.update({/*..*/});
```

or should I just do like?

```
const ref = db.collection(/*..*/).doc(/*..*/);
const snapshot = await ref.get();
/* so on.../*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a new reference from your snapshot constant then its possible
I would so it this way
**example**

```
const areaSnapshot = await admin.firestore().doc("areas/greater-boston").get()
const bostonCities = areaSnapshot.data().cities;
const allAreas = await areaSnapshot.ref.parent.doc("new-york").get()
const nyCities= allAreas.data().cities
console.log(bostonCities, nyCities)
```

update document

```
    //to update document
    const areaSnapshot = await admin.firestore().doc("areas/greater-boston").get()
    const allAreas = areaSnapshot.ref.parent.doc("new-york").update({
                    capital: {
                        liberty: true
                    }
                })
     await allAreas
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("success")
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Yup its one of the attribute in snapshot.

Comment: Nope, this does not work like `snapshot.ref.parent.update()` (is not a function)

Comment: you should instead write it as snapshot.ref.parent.doc('').update(object)

Comment: Unless you want to add a new document then snapshot.ref.parent.doc('').add can be used
I recommend using a syntax help in your editor makes the coding easier as it explains the attributes an object has while you type.